# Lua io.read() and io.write() on Ti-Nspire

Tags: input, lua, output, ti-nspire

```
io.read()
io.write()
```

Is not working for Ti-Nspire

How should I use this right

Comment: `io.write()` with no arguments produces no output.

Comment: Of course! That's not my problem. There's an error at this line.

Comment: "an error" are you serious?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to run with a special software for Ti-Nspire @Piglet

Comment: you can't just say "an error" expecting others to help you. you have to provide more information like the actual error message... please read [ask]

Comment: I forgot it and I don't have the software available now

Answer (score 2):

From the [TI-Nspire Lua Scripting API Reference Guide](https://education.ti.com/download/en/ed-tech/59108CCE54484B76AF68879C217D47B2/7EFB09CED41C4190AFF8F60283B6727A/TI-Nspire%20Lua%20Scripting%20API%20Reference%20Guide.pdf) Page 2:

> The following standard Lua libraries are not available in the TI-Nspire software: file **io** os debug

The io library does not exist hence you cannot use any of its functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `io.read()` and `io.write()`. There is `print()` (which works as expected), but it's only meant to be used for debugging. If you need a console for your program, you might as well write your own. You could also use Jens' Script Editor (I use it) https://www.ticalc.org/archives/files/fileinfo/464/46492.html which is standard nspire lua + a console you can use (with `io.read()` and `io.write()`)